# Icons not visible till you interact with the page (mouseover)

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem i have some social icons on the webpage. The first time you load the page the icons aren't visible.

When i go over the icon it becomes visible and stays visible.

```
.social-icons-float .social-icon {
   display: block;
   padding-bottom: 5px;
   font-size: 13px;
}

.social-icons-float .social-icon .social-count {
   display: block;
   border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 12px 0px;
   font-size: 24px;
   font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #a0a0a0;
   position: relative;
   margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.social-icons-float .social-icon .social-count .social-arrow {
   display: block;
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 10px;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: -10px;
   width: 100%;
}
```

could some one please help me

Comment: Welcome on SO! How could we see or reproduce the problem? A jsfiddle/codepen for example, HTML code. Which browser(s) did you test with (in which OS and which version of both)?

Comment: the problem is in google chrome.

Comment: @user3460377, you're right. I have been through the same! It was a bug rendering the image...Nothing to do with the code :) Don't worry.

Comment: What about other browsers: OK, fail, didn't test? Which ones?

Comment: it is only google chrome the rest works perfect

Comment: Are you loading HTML images as @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan is implying or something else like font-face icons? Did yout try adding `min-width/min-height`; if these are HTML images did you add with and height attributes on img element?

Comment: they are font-face-icons

Answer (score 0):

That happens sometimes and is more generally seen in Google Chrome. Some of the images on sites are just blocks of border 1px. Once you mouseover them they are visible.

I know that, its just the bug nothing to do with the code here! :-)

Comment: indeed is google chrome and nothing i can do about it?

Comment: Nope, that is a bug in Google Chrome! They're gonna fix this. You can't do anything related to this....